# Is Bhavishya Purana authentic?

Tags: puranas, bhavishya-purana

Wiki says:

> The Bhavishya Purana (Bhaviṣya Purāṇa) is one of the eighteen major works in the Purana genre of Hinduism, written in Sanskrit.[1][2] The title Bhavishya means "future" and implies it is a work that contains prophecies regarding the future, however, the "prophecy" parts of the extant manuscripts are a modern era work. Those sections of the surviving manuscripts that are dated to be older, are partly borrowed from other Indian texts such as Brihat Samhita and Shamba Purana. The veracity and authenticity of much of the Bhavishya Purana has been questioned by modern scholarship, and the text is considered an example of "constant revisions and living nature" of Puranic genre of Hindu literature.

The text exists in many inconsistent versions, wherein the content as well as their subdivisions vary, and five major versions are known. Some manuscripts have four Parvan (parts), some two, others don't have any parts. The text as it exists today is a composite of material ranging from medieval era to very recent. The available versions of Bhavishya Purana are based on a printed text published during the British colonial era."

does it overlap Nostradamus?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73815/discussion-on-question-by-s-k-is-bhavishya-purana-authentic).

Comment: It's best to take it with a Grain of salt. Bhavishya Purana contains many nonsensical stories in the name of predictions such as Shankaracharya spreading Shaivism by the order of Ramanujacharya, Chaitanya being a smarta and meeting with bhattojidiksita who literally lived 2 centuries after him and so on and so foth

Answer (score 4):

Obviously it is. It is one among the 18 major Puranas of Hinduism.

From the [Devi Bhagavata Purana's 1st book's 3rd chapter](http://www.astrojyoti.com/devibhagavatam1-2.htm):

> 1-11. Sûta said :-- “O best of the Munis! I am now telling you the
>   names of the Purânas, etc., exactly as I have heard from Veda Vyâsa,
>   the son of Satyavati; listen. The Purâna beginning with "ma" are two
>   in number; those beginning with “bha” are two; those beginning with
>   “bra" are three; those beginning with "va” are four; those beginning
>   respectively with “A”, “na”, “pa”, “Ling”, “ga”, “kû” and “Ska” are
>   one each and “ma” means Matsya Purâna, Mârkandeya Purâna; **“Bha”
>   signifies Bhavisya, Bhâgavat Purânas;** “Bra” signifies Brahmâ,
>   Brahmânda and Brahmâvaivarta Purânas; “va” signifies Vâman, Vayu,
>   Visnu and Varaha Purânas; “A” signifies Agni Purâna; “Na” signifies
>   Narada Purâna; “Pa” signifies Padma Purâna; “Ling” signifies Linga
>   Purânam; “Ga” signifies Govinda Purânam; Kû signifies Kurma Purâna and
>   “Ska” signifies Skanda Purânam. **These are the eighteen Purânas**.

And, as regards, the number of Slokas the Purana has, it says this:

> In the Matsya Purâna there are fourteen thousand slokas; in the
>   wonderfully varied Markandeya Purânam there are nine thousand slokas.
>   **In the Bhavisya Purâna fourteen thousand and five hundred slokas are
>   counted by the Munis**, the seers of truth. In the holy Bhâgavata there
>   are eighteen thousand S’lokas; in the Brahmâ Purâna there are Ajuta
>   (ten thousand) S’lokas