# Is the BORI Critical Edition of the Mahabharata the most authentic?

Tags: mahabharata, critical-edition

Is BORI Critical Edition <s>translated by Bibek Debroy</s> truly the most authentic version available on this planet right now?

Comment: This is opinion based question as all may not agree with methodology of BORI used to prepare critical edition.

Comment: This is purely opinion based, I am not voting to close though.

Comment: your question is opinion based. please read forum rules

Comment: Not sure why this is closed as "opinion-based" we have similar questions questioning the authenticity of other scriptures. Examples: [Is Baskala Shaka of Rig veda Authentic?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/32906) [Is Yog Vasistha authentic scripture?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/32853) [Is Bhavishya Purana authentic?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24650)

Comment: @sv. yes I agree.But asking about authencity of a particular scripture is different from that of a particular edition of a scripture---isn't it?

Comment: If this is not going to be re-opened, yes, BORI CE is the most authentic version of Mahabharata out there. As for Bibek Debroy's English translation, some say it's not as good as Kisari Mohan Ganguli's available here: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/maha/index.htm

Comment: "But asking about authenticity of a particular scripture is different from that of a particular edition of a scripture" - agree both things are different. But how is asking if a certain scripture is authentic not opinion-based but asking if a particular edition is? Authentic in the case of a CE simply means it's the most reliable account of a story e.g., Mahabharata. @commonman

Comment: @sv. The authenticity of a scripture can be judged from its acceptance in other scriptures or commentaries.But acceptance of a particular edition, that being a modern one, has to be purely opinion based.

Comment: @sv. I personally will always check the critical editions though, as large parts of the scriptures are interpolations:)

Comment: See the first comment under [Is Yoga Vasistha authentic scripture?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/32853): "Please define what is meant by authentic." -- so the community has allowed that question without defining "authentic" and yet closes this one. @commonman

Comment: @commonman You said under the other question: "authenticity of an ancient text has no meaning" and here you say "authenticity of a scripture can be judged from its acceptance in other scriptures or commentaries" - so what's your stand now?

Comment: @sv. yes, thats a bit surprising. I agree.

Comment: "as large parts of the scriptures are interpolations" -- and now this question starts making sense, isn't it? 'authentic' meaning majority of the interpolations removed? @commonman

Comment: @sv. My stand regarding the authencity of the scriptures is the same that I wrote there. That scripture isvaccepted in outpr tradition.But as I said, choosingnwhich part of the scripture is authentic and which oart is not has to be opinion based.Somevwould go with the texts received by guru parampara, others like me will check from the critical edition.:)

Comment: 'Some would go with the texts received by guru parampara, others like me will check from the critical edition' - agree and this explanation (with some references) should be part of an answer. @commonman

Comment: @sv. yes, but the question is how can one understand which one is interpolation and which one is not and the methodology adopted in making the CE amy notvappeal to all, especially those who rely on texts received through 'guru-parampara'.

Comment: @sv. okay, I voted to reopen:)

Comment: @commonman Thanks. Think we should write something along these lines as the answer: https://www.quora.com/Which-edition-of-Mahabharat-is-authentic

Comment: @sv Thank you so much. But KMG has included some events which were later declared as interpolations by BORI.

Comment: @commonman If there is a Q that is opinion based then this is the one ..pls ping me when it gets reopened again.. i will cast my close vote ... If Bori (whose credibility itself is doubtful) is allowed to do surgery on our scriptures then that's terribly bad news ..it's like people altering our history as per their whims ...

Comment: @Rickross this question can be closed again because its only 2 votes now for closure. There are sure 5 users who will close this again!!!

Comment: @Rickross Why is BORI's credibility doubtful? That's what I want to know. I'm looking for an authentic version of our history. If you can recommend one, it will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: @Rishita You can read 'Interpolations in Mahabharata' [here](https://archive.org/stream/InterpolationsInTheMahabharata#mode/2up) - but not all of them have been removed from the CE. Yes KMG version has lot of stories added from here and there. That's because he used more than one recension for his translation - see [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26107).

Comment: @commonman Please ping me before pinging Rickross 

Comment: What is the credibility of BORI is a different Q .. I myself asked a Q about it earlier .. Your Q will be closed because you ask " Is it the MOST authentic?" ..If I ask Qs like "Is Shiva the HIGHEST God?" or " Which Purana is the MOST authentic?" those will be closed for sure @RishitaGhosh